# Compute Left Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How does one compute the left eigenvectors of a matrix? I cannot seem to quite get the answer.. I don't care what the matrix is. Let's just say I have matrix $A$ and have found the 'right' eigenvectors $e$ and I want to compute the left eigenvectors. Do we $A^Te = c$ Then the left eigenvector is $c^T$? I did this for a 2x2 and it seemed to work, but for a 3x3 it did not (according to the answers in the book).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Left eigenvectors $x$ are computed from $x^TA=\lambda x^T$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, the left (resp. right) eigenvectors of a matrix $A$ are the right (resp. left) eigenvectors of the matrix $A^T$. It follows quite straightforwardly that the eigenvalues of $A$ and those of $A^T$ coincide (including multiplicities) but the same is not true of the left and right eigenvectors. Generally, one simply needs to compute the, say, right eigenvectors even if one already has the left eigenvectors. Of course, for special matrices (like symmetric ones), left and right eigenvectors do coincide.

Comment: I am still failing to see how to compute these (from both answers). I've tried column operations, but I just cant 'see' how to find the left eigenvectors.

Comment: they are the right eigenvectors of $A^T$, so if you know how to compute right eigenvectors, then you are done.

Answer (score 2):

With $ uA = ku $ you do this

$ (u A ) ^* = k^* u^* $ where * means complex conjugate, and you get
$ A^* u^* = k^* u^* $

That should do it

Answer (score 0):

The right (and left) eigen vectors $P_i$  (respectively, $Q_j$), satisfy
$$AP_i=\lambda_i P_i\qquad A^TQ_i=\lambda_i Q_i$$
Therefore, the matrix $P$ formed by vectors
$$P=(P_1 \mid \ldots \mid P_k) $$ satisfy
$$AP=PD$$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix containing $\lambda_1, \lambda_2,\ldots,\lambda_k.$

It can be shown that the right eigen vectors are independent, hence it
has inverse $P^{-1}$.

We get,
$$A=PDP^{-1}$$
Similarly one can form $Q$ matrix and $A^T=QDQ^{-1}$ and write $(A^T)^T=(Q^T)^{-1}DQ^T$

If $A$ is symmetric, i.e $A=(A^T)^T,$ we get $Q^T=P^{-1}.$

That is, for a **symmetric** matrix, the *transpose of the left eigen matrix* of $A$ is the *inverse of right eigen matrix*!

In the case of nonsymmetric matrix, we don't have such relationship. They are to be computed separtely.